# Motivation for dual bases

Tags: vector-spaces, algebraic-number-theory

I am encountering dual bases for the first time in the context of algebraic number theory, mainly in proofs regarding the existence of an integral basis for $\mathcal{O}_K$ and its ideals. I am wondering about motivation for defining a dual basis and intuitively what it is. So far I have been working through examples with only a definitional understanding of a dual basis (as in I accept that they are formal mathematical objects), but I'd like to understand why they are important and how.

Comment: One nice property of dual bases is that, relative to those bases, the matrix of the adjoint of a linear transformation is simply the (conjugate) transpose of its matrix.